# Spring Data Rest user repository BCCrypt password

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a spring data rest custom user repository in which password need to be encrypted using BCCrypt. From the UI I am sending the plain password, I want to know where to convert the plain password into BCCrypt hash before hibernate creates user in DB. Should I use before save interceptor and hash the password? Or is there any way I can tell spring to use password encoder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password encoding with Spring Data REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260582/password-encoding-with-spring-data-rest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in your `Registration-Service`, like the following:

```
    @Autowired 
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    ...
    public void registerUser(final User user)
    {
        final String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        userRepo.save(user);
    }
```

The password-encoder i refer you, is the `org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder` this encoder automatically generate a salt for you.

Comment: If you use Spring-Data-Rest you won't hit any service layer? How would you be able to insert this Service before the Repository when using the implicit Spring-Data-Rest controllers?

Comment: @ManuZi have you been able to resolve this? I'm aware that I can implement a service layer that encodes and delegates the persistence job to the repository, but I'm looking for a more elegant and lightweight solution that uses only implicit JPA repositories. Can we somehow configure JPA to do that?

Comment: I think there is no other "elegant" way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 13):

The way to intercept inserts in Spring Data Rest is using an event handler.

**NOTE:** This code won't work with PATCH operations that don't include the password field.

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(User.class)
public class UserEventHandler {

  @Autowired 
  private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

  @Autowired 
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @HandleBeforeCreate     
  public void handleUserCreate(User user) {
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
  }

  @HandleBeforeSave
  public void handleUserUpdate(User user) {
    if (user.getPassword() == null || user.getPassword().equals("")) {
        //keeps the last password
        User storedUser = userRepository.getOne(user.getId());
        user.setPassword(storedUser.getPassword());
    }
    else {
        //password change request
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What when the user exists, and is a password update?

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli Then you should implement a similar method annotated with "@HandleBeforeSave"

Comment: It's not feasible, because if I send a PATCH request w/o the password, the User instance will contain the encrypted password (loaded from the database) and you would encrypt it twice.

Comment: HandleBeforeSave is called only with updates (PATCH and PUT) and not with inserts (POST), so you can do a different implementations. I updated my response with an implementation of that method.

Comment: The implementation is not right, because Spring Data REST on PATCH operations (w/o the password set) will pass a User instance with the password property populated from the database. Therefore you'll end up encrypting an already encrypted password.

Comment: That's true. I ended using always PUT, because Spring Data Rest PATCH is not very RESTful standard and I had other issues with it. By the way, you can send an empty password in PATCH operations always (except password change requests), so it won't be populated from database.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think this can be called a solution. You're basically inhibiting anyone else from using your APIs. The problem is *not* Spring Data REST but the solution you're proposing. You should use a custom JsonDeserializer on the password field and encrypt the incoming password when the JSON is deserialized, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260582/password-encoding-with-spring-data-rest/30723658

Comment: Ok, I admit that solution it's ok for the general case. In my case, I removed PATCH verb from my users endpoint (and other endpoints) because the implementation of it in Spring data rest gives is not standard and problematic (recommeded read: http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/). So I shouldn't call it "inhibiting anyone from using my APIs".

Comment: It's good that you added a notice on top of the answer. Have a good one!